# Cors blocking when trying to use mgt-login and mgt-msal-provider

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I cant seem to understand why im getting this problem, can anyone please help im developing in C# MVC web application

- authority = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0 (without {}) (remove the /v2.0 that fixed it for me thanks to Nikola Metulev comment :))
- appId = client_id

```
<script src=@string.Format("https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js")></script>
```

```
<mgt-msal-provider client-id=@appId
    login-type="popup"
    scopes="user.read,people.read"
    authority=@authority></mgt-msal-provider>

<mgt-login id="header-login" class="header-login"></mgt-login>
```

[Picture of the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbsPr.png)

also when trying to connect to the login through mvc C# it works fine no cors errors there.

in javascript ive tried this to try and solve the cors error but did nothing

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
    this.origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    this.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    this.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    this.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
}
```

used * to just try and get it to work (also tried https://localhost:44375)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration) documentation, the authority should be in this format:

- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/`, where  is the tenant ID of the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant or a domain associated with this Azure AD tenant. Used only to sign in users of a specific organization.
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/`. Used to sign in users with work and school accounts or personal Microsoft accounts.
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/`. Used to sign in users with work and school accounts.
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/`. Used to sign in users with only personal Microsoft accounts (formerly known as Windows Live ID accounts).

Try removing the `v2.0` from your authority string and see if that fixes the issue:

authority = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/<s>v2.0</s>